# ¿Que diferencias tienen las funciones sendall & send en python?

Tags: python, socket

En Python, en el módulo `socket` hay dos funciones: `send()` y `sendall()`, ambas tienen los mismos parámetros y la documentación de ambas es bastante similar que no llego a comprender del todo que diferencias hay entre una y otra ya que al menos para mí pareciera que hacen lo mismo.

```
from socket import *

s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",9000))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c,a=s.accept()
    print "servidor \n"
    print "recived connection from ", a
    dat=c.recv(1000)
    c.sendall("hello %s\n"%a[0])
    c.send("hola")
    print c.recv(1000)
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estamos hablando de la rama 2x de Python, vayamos a la documentación del módulo [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

- **`socket.send(string[, flags])`**: Enviar datos al socket. El socket debe estar conectado a un socket remoto. El argumento opcional flags tiene el mismo significado que el anterior para recv(). Devuelve el número de bytes enviados. Las aplicaciones son responsables de comprobar que se han enviado todos los datos; si sólo se han transmitido algunos de ellos, la aplicación debe intentar entregar los datos restantes
- **`socket.sendall(string[, flags])`**: Enviar datos al socket. El socket debe estar conectado a un socket remoto. El argumento opcional flags tiene el mismo significado que el anterior para recv(). A **diferencia de `send()`, este método continúa enviando datos desde una cadena hasta que todos los datos han sido enviados o hasta que ocurre un error. `None` es devuelto en caso de éxito. En caso de error, se plantea una excepción y no hay forma de determinar la cantidad de datos, si los hubiera, que se hayan enviado correctamente**.

Básicamente `send()` es una función de bajo nivel, si la usas te debes hacer cargo de verificar que efectivamente se hubieran enviado todos los datos, por el contrario `sendall()` es una implementación de mayor nivel que te asegura que se enviaran todos los datos a menos, claro, que surja un error.